# Using a different App-ID, what are the consequences?

Tags: ios, apple, appstore

The company I work for has recently been given an order to improve an App that is previously developed by a different company. They use a bundle identifier like com.theircompany.appname, however, I cannot register that bundle ID for generating an App ID for APNs.

I wonder what the consequences are if I change the bundle ID to, say, com.mycompany.appname?

Comment: Changes made to the developer site in 2013 made it possible to both delete AppIDs and transfer apps. The current owner initiates the transfer on their account. The recipient accepts the transfer on theirs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody will know it is the same application.

It will not be presented as an upgrade, but as a different application in the App Store. Thus it will also be possible to have both versions installed on the same device. If it is a paid app, the user will have to pay twice.

Comment: OK, thanks, should've seen that of course :). But then I'd like to know how to transfer that bundle ID (or App ID) to our company's account, but I'll probably have to ask that again :P

Comment: I recently tried to juggle app ids between my company's apple developer account and my client's developer account, and I discovered to my shock and horror that it's actually *not possible* to delete an app ID from an account, and (as you've found) the portal prevents you from duplicating an id with another account. I honestly don't know how you're supposed to handle cases where a company hires somebody else to finish or maintain a project.

Comment: Dan - I would argue the client should be do the publishing.  I don't know the inner workings of how an application is punlished, can you setup additional accounts connected to the developer account and add/remove said access?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to transfer an App ID unless you acquire the entire corporation under whose developer account that App ID was registered.

It is currently not possible to delete an App ID.  App ID's are forever.

Any different or changes to an App ID will result in a completely new app in the App store, unrelated to the previous one.